# MT19937 does NOT reproduce the same pseudo-random sequence by holding the seed value a constant

Tags: random, fortran, mersenne-twister

I'm writing a checkpoint function in my Monte Carlo simulation in Fortran 90/95, the compiler I'm using is ifort 18.0.2, before going through detail just to clarify the version of pseudo-random generator I'm using:

```
A C-program for MT19937, with initialization, improved 2002/1/26.
Coded by Takuji Nishimura and Makoto Matsumoto.

Code converted to Fortran 95 by Josi Rui Faustino de Sousa
Date: 2002-02-01
```

See [mt19937](http://web.mst.edu/~vojtat/class_5403/mt19937/mt19937ar.f90) for the source code.

The general structure of my Monte Carlo simulation code is given below:

```
program montecarlo
 call read_iseed(...)
 call mc_subroutine(...)
end
```

Within the `read_iseed`

```
subroutine read_iseed(...)
  use mt19937

    if (Restart == 'n') then

    call system('od -vAn -N4 -td4 < /dev/urandom > '//trim(IN_ISEED)
    open(unit=7,file=trim(IN_ISEED),status='old')
    read(7,*) i
    close(7)

    !This is only used to initialise the PRNG sequence
    iseed = abs(i)
    else if (Restart == 'y') then

    !Taking seed value from the latest iteration of previous simulation
    iseed = RestartSeed

    endif

    call init_genrand(iseed)
    print *, 'first pseudo-random value ',genrand_real3(), 'iseed ',iseed

    return
end subroutine
```

Based on my understanding, if the seed value holds a constant, the PRNG should be able to reproduce the pseudo-random sequence every time?

In order to prove this is the case, I ran two individual simulations by using the same seed value, they are able to reproduce the exact sequence. So far so good!

Based on the previous test, I'd further assume that regardless the number of times `init_genrand()` being called **within** one individual simulation, the PRNG should also be able to reproduce the pseudo-random value sequence? So I did a little modification to my `read_iseed()` subroutine

```
subroutine read_iseed(...)
  use mt19937

    if (Restart == 'n') then

    call system('od -vAn -N4 -td4 < /dev/urandom > '//trim(IN_ISEED)
    open(unit=7,file=trim(IN_ISEED),status='old')
    read(7,*) i
    close(7)

    !This is only used to initialise the PRNG sequence
    iseed = abs(i)
    else if (Restart == 'y') then

    !Taking seed value from the latest iteration of the previous simulation
    iseed = RestartSeed

    endif

    call init_genrand(iseed)
    print *, 'first time initialisation ',genrand_real3(), 'iseed ',iseed

    call init_genrand(iseed)
    print *, 'second time initialisation ',genrand_real3(), 'iseed ',iseed

    return
end subroutine
```

The output is surprisingly not the case I thought would be, by all means `iseed` outputs are identical in between two initializations, however, `genrand_real3()` outputs are not identical.

Because of this unexpected result, I struggled with resuming the simulation at an arbitrary state of the system since the simulation is not reproducing the latest configuration state of the system I'm simulating.

I'm not sure if I've provided enough information, please let me know if any part of this question needs to be more specific?

Comment: Please use tag [tagnfortran] for all Fortran questions. There is no point taging poth fortran90 and fortran95, your question is not version-specifci anyway.

Comment: How does `init_genrand` populate the full PRNG state?

Comment: @francescalus pls see [mt19937ar]{http://web.mst.edu/~vojtat/class_5403/mt19937/mt19937ar.f90}, my first test proved that it's able to reproduce the sequence by feeding it with a constant seed value, but in my second test when I re-initialised the sequence with the same seed value, it somehow did not reset the state of sequence to back to where it started. function `init_genrand` as I'm reading the subroutine, it seems to me that `init_genrand()` initialises where the sequence starts by given a seed value, and `genrand_real3()` provides a value in (0,1). Any chance you see any disagreements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source code you've provided (See [mt19937]{http://web.mst.edu/~vojtat/class_5403/mt19937/mt19937ar.f90} for the source code.), the `init_genrand` **does not clear** the whole state.

There are 3 critical state variables:

```
integer( kind = wi )  :: mt(n)            ! the array for the state vector
logical( kind = wi )  :: mtinit = .false._wi   ! means mt[N] is not initialized
integer( kind = wi )  :: mti = n + 1_wi   ! mti==N+1 means mt[N] is not initialized
```

The first one is the "array for the state vector", second one is a flag that ensures we don't start with uninitialized array, and the third one is some position marker, as I guess from the condition stated in the comment.

Looking at `subroutine init_genrand( s )`, it sets `mtinit` flag, and fills the `mt()` array from `1` upto `n`. Alright.

Looking at `genrand_real3` it's based on `genrand_int32`.

Looking at `genrand_int32`, it starts up with

```
if ( mti > n ) then ! generate N words at one time
  ! if init_genrand() has not been called, a default initial seed is used
  if ( .not. mtinit ) call init_genrand( seed_d )
```

and does its arithmetic magic and then starts getting the result:

```
y = mt(mti)
mti = mti + 1_wi
```

so.. `mti` is a positional index in the 'state array', and it is incremented by 1 after each integer read from the generator.

Back to `init_genrand` - remember? it have been resetting the array `mt()` but it **has not resetted the MTI** back to its starting `mti = n + 1_wi`.

I bet this is the cause of the phenomenon you've observed, since after re-initializing with the same seed, the array would be filled with the same set of values, but later the int32 generator would read from a different starting point.  I doubt it was intended, so it's probably a tiny bug easy to overlook.

Comment: apparently I'm not the only person who's into the bug, it's a known issue of implementing checkpoint restart based upon mt19937, resetting positional index requires the knowledge of exact total number of times genrand_real() and genrand_int() being called, and there isn't a general fix for this since it depends on the application. But cheers for pointing the issue out!